# Can screen readers use chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm writing a chrome extension to allow users to quickly post things to my website.

Because I'm designing for chrome, I have the advantage of not worrying about cross-browser compatibility -- if the user uses Chromium, I'm all set.

That being said, I'm wondering about accessibility. Should I be designing with the assumption that screen reader users may be using my chrome extension? Are there any screen readers which parse chrome extensions? Are there any screen reader users out there who use chrome extensions?

I tried my best to google this question, but I could only find information related to "screen reader chrome extensions", which is not what I want... Lol.

Any input is welcome.

Comment: If your extension shows a UI, it can be parsed by a screen reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be designing with the assumption that screen reader users may be using my chrome extension?

Absolutely. Screen reader users are just like any other users and can benefit from plugins that enhance productivity.

> Are there any screen readers which parse chrome extensions?

I don't know about that. You'd need to provide more information on what your plugin does. For example, there are plugins that help find accessibility issues by highlighting various structural elements on the page, such as headings, lists, and tables. If that plugin didn't allow for customization of colors and fonts, then it might cause an accessibility issue.